# Find the value of $\big|\frac{\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_0}{\cos^2\theta_2}+\frac{\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_0}{\sin^2\theta_2}\big|$

Tags: trigonometry

If $$\dfrac{\cos\theta_1}{\cos\theta_2}+\dfrac{\sin\theta_1}{\sin\theta_2}=\dfrac{\cos\theta_0}{\cos\theta_2}+\dfrac{\sin\theta_0}{\sin\theta_2}=1,$$ where $\theta_1$ and $\theta_0$ do not differ by an odd multiple of $\pi$, then find the value of $$\left|\dfrac{\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_0}{\cos^2\theta_2}+\dfrac{\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_0}{\sin^2\theta_2}\right|.$$

My attempt is as follows:

**Attempt $1$:**

$$\dfrac{\cos\theta_1}{\cos\theta_2}+\dfrac{\sin\theta_1}{\sin\theta_2}=\dfrac{\cos\theta_0}{\cos\theta_2}+\dfrac{\sin\theta_0}{\sin\theta_2}$$

$$\dfrac{\sin\left(\theta_1+\theta_2\right)}{\cos\theta_2\sin\theta_2}=\dfrac{\sin\left(\theta_0+\theta_2\right)}{\cos\theta_2\sin\theta_2}$$

$$\sin\left(\theta_1+\theta_2\right)-\sin\left(\theta_0+\theta_2\right)=0$$
$$2\sin\dfrac{\left(\theta_1-\theta_0\right)}{2}\cos\dfrac{2\theta_2+\theta_1+\theta_0}{2}=0$$

either $\theta_1-\theta_0=2n\pi$  or  $2\theta_2+\theta_1+\theta_0=2n\pi$

Unfortunately it is given that $\theta_1-\theta_0$ is not equal to odd multiple of $\pi$ but we are getting $\theta_1-\theta_0$ as even multiple of $\pi$ so we cannot rule out one of the factor. Due to this reason I didn't find any way ahead.

**Attempt $2$:**

$$\dfrac{\cos\theta_1}{\cos\theta_2}+\dfrac{\sin\theta_1}{\sin\theta_2}=1$$
$$\sin\left(\theta_1+\theta_2\right)=\cos\theta_2\sin\theta_2$$
$$2\sin\left(\theta_1+\theta_2\right)=\sin2\theta\tag{1}$$

In the similary way

$$2\sin\left(\theta_0+\theta_1\right)=\sin2\theta\tag{2}$$

But by doing this we are tending towards result obtained in **Attempt $1$:**

**Attempt $3$:**

$$\left|\left(1-\dfrac{\sin\theta_0}{\sin\theta_2}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{\sin\theta_1}{\sin\theta_2}\right)+\dfrac{\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_0}{\sin^2\theta_2}\right|$$

$$\left|1-\dfrac{\sin\theta_1}{\sin\theta_2}-\dfrac{\sin\theta_0}{\sin\theta_2}+\dfrac{2\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_0}{\sin^2\theta_2}\right|$$

Also not getting anything from here, what to do?

Comment: If you can't rule out a factor, see what happens in each case.

Comment: Just FYI (I'm not going to revert, because it really doesn't matter that much, but...):  MathJaX should be used for formatting things that are fundamentally mathematical, and is not appropriate for non-mathematical entities such as the indices of an enumerated list.  [This answer on meta has more details.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29924/468350)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Observe that $\theta_1,\theta_0$ are the roots of

$$\cos x\sin\theta_2+\sin x\cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_2=0$$

$$\iff\cos x\sin\theta_2=\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_2(\sin\theta_2-\sin x)$$

Now squaring both sides and replacing $\cos^2 x$ with $1-\sin^2x,$ we find

$$(1-\sin^2x)\sin^2\theta_2=\cos^2\theta_2(\sin\theta_2-\sin x)^2$$

$$\implies \sin^2x-\sin x\cdot 2\cos^2\theta_2\sin\theta_2-\sin^2\theta_2(1-\cos^2\theta_2)=0$$

So, $\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_0=-\dfrac{\sin^4\theta_2}1$

Similarly, $\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_0=?$

Comment: great, nailed it.

Comment: only one thing I didn't understand, why in the question, condition is given that $\theta_1-\theta_0\ne n\pi$ where $n$ is odd

Comment: @user3290550, Let me try to find out

Comment: one correction in quadratic equation , it should be 

$$\sin^2x-2\sin x\cos^2\theta_2\sin\theta_2-\sin^2\theta_2(1-\cos^2\theta_2)=0$$

Comment: @user3290550, Please feel free to rectify

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\sin\dfrac{\theta_0-\theta_1}2\cos\dfrac{\theta_0+\theta_1-2\theta_2}2=0$$

If $\sin\dfrac{\theta_0-\theta_1}2=0,$ this will make both equations identical

$$\implies\cos\dfrac{\theta_0+\theta_1-2\theta_2}2=0\implies\dfrac{\theta_0+\theta_1-2\theta_2}2=\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}2$$  for some integer $n$

$\implies\theta_0+\theta_1=2n\pi+\pi-2\theta_2$

$$1=\left(\dfrac{\cos\theta_1}{\cos\theta_2}+\dfrac{\sin\theta_1}{\sin\theta_2}\right)\left(\dfrac{\cos\theta_0}{\cos\theta_2}+\dfrac{\sin\theta_0}{\sin\theta_2}\right) =\dfrac{\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_0}{\cos^2\theta_2}+\dfrac{\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_0}{\sin^2\theta_2}+\dfrac{\sin(\theta_0+\theta_1)}{\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_2}$$

Replace the value of $\theta_0+\theta_1$ in the last term

Comment: yeah so what is the problem if equations get identical?

Comment: don't you think question should have said that $\theta_1-\theta_0$ is not the multiple of $\pi$ or even multiple of $\pi$?